# How to ignore null value while fetching the data from database table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to ignore **null value** while fetching the data from database table php mysql. Anyone please help me

**My mysql query is :**

```
$sql = "SELECT  DISTINCT cuid FROM temp_donor_list WHERE donor_no='$name'";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT cuid FROM temp_donor_list WHERE donor_no='$name' and cuid!='' and donor_no!=''";
```

Comment: `''`(blank) is not equal to `NULL`. `NULL` is special value so you can not compare with `blank` string

Comment: This query executed correctly:

$sql = "SELECT  DISTINCT cuid FROM temp_donor_list WHERE donor_no='$name' AND cuid!=' '";

Answer (score 1):

1. If your field contains `NULL` value then you can use `IS NOT NULL` condtion.
2. If your field contains `blank string` then you can use `<>` opertor

   `SELECT DISTINCT cuid FROM temp_donor_list  WHERE donor_no='$name'  AND cuid IS NOT NULL AND cuid<>''`